# How do I redirect Django commands using PyDev?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, redirect, pydev

I would like to run the following Django command (to dump the contents of my database into a text file):

```
python manage.py dumpdata my_app > data.json
```

I'm using the Django framework within [PyDev](http://pydev.org) as an Eclipse plugin. Therefore, in order to run the above command in PyDev I go to "Custom command" and insert `dumpdata my_app > data.json`. However, doing so results in an error because of the `>` character:

> Error: Unknown application: >

How can I use `>` (redirection) in PyDev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Eclipse and go to menu Run > Run configurations
2. Click on Pydev Django and then the "New" icon to create a new launch configuration
3. Tab main: select the project and main module (`manage.py`)
4. Tab interpreter: select which interpreter will run manage.py
5. Tab arguments: write `dumpdata my_app` in Program arguments
6. Tab common: check File in "Standard input and Output" and set your output location and filename. Uncheck "Allocate console".

Finally click on Apply and Run. A bit tricky but works as it should.

Comment: It works, though  considering the number of steps required for the task in Eclipse, I'd better just `dumpdata` using the command line (not inside Eclipse).